# When removing an item from a list in a list of objects, that item is also removed from the other objects' list

Tags: python, list

So I have a class called cell:

```
class cell:
    possibles = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]
    value = None;

    def __init__(self, value):
        if value == "":
            self.value = "0"
        else:
            self.value = value

if __name__=="__main__":
    mlist = [cell("2"), cell("6"), cell("8")]
    mlist[2].possibles.remove("3")
    print mlist[0].possibles
```

The output is:

```
['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Why would it remove a value from possibles in the first item of the array, when I explicitly removed it from the third item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common Python gotcha. The way this is written every `cell` has a reference to the same list instance. You can check this by printing `id(mlist[i].possibles)` for each `i`.

To create separate lists, move the initialization to the constructor:

```
def __init__(self, value):
    self.possibles = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]
```

Comment: I wish I could mod this and the post directly below. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have defined `possibilities` to be a class variable, not an instance variable.

Move `possibilities` into `__init__` (as `self.possibilities`), and you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

```
mlist = [cell("2"), cell("6"), cell("8")]
```

here you don't have three different lists, but three references to the same list. Any change affects all.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should make possibles an instance variable.  You can also do without the if...else clause by making the value parameter default to 0.

```
    class cell:
        def __init__(self, value=0):
            self.possibles = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" ]
            self.value = value

    if __name__=="__main__":
        mlist = [cell("2"), cell("6"), cell("8")]
        mlist[2].possibles.remove("3")


>>> mlist[0].possibles
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> mlist[2].possibles
['1', '2', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>>
```